# Install spark on yarn cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, vagrant, hadoop-yarn, bigdata

I am looking for a guide regarding how to install spark on an existing virtual yarn cluster.

I have a yarn cluster consisting of two nodes, ran map-reduce job which worked perfect. Looked for results in log and everything is working fine.

Now I need to add the spark installation commands and configurations files in my vagrantfile. I can't find a good guide, could someone give me a good link ?

I used this guide for the yarn cluster

http://www.alexjf.net/blog/distributed-systems/hadoop-yarn-installation-definitive-guide/#single-node-installation

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about vagrant, but I have installed Spark on top of hadoop 2.6 (in the guide referred to as post-YARN) and I hope this helps.

Installing Spark on an existing hadoop is really easy, you just need to install it **only on one** machine. For that you have to download the one pre-built for your hadoop version from [it's official website](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) (I guess you can use the `without hadoop` version but you need to point it to the direction of hadoop binaries in your system). Then decompress it:

```
tar -xvf spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.x.tgz -C /opt
```

Now you only need to set some environment variables. First in your `~/.bashrc` (or `~/.zshrc`) you can set `SPARK_HOME` and add it to your `PATH` if you want:

```
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop-2.x
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin
```

Also for this changes to take effect you can run:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Second you need to point Spark to your Hadoop configuartion directories. To do this set these two environmental variables in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh`:

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=[your-hadoop-conf-dir usually $HADOOP_PREFIX/etc/hadoop]
export YARN_CONF_DIR=[your-yarn-conf-dir usually the same as the last variable]
```

If this file doesn't exist, you can copy the contents of `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh.template` and start from there.

Now to start the shell in yarn mode you can run:

```
spark-shell --master yarn --deploy-mode client
```

(You can't run the shell in `cluster` deploy-mode)

**----------- Update**

I forgot to mention that you can also submit cluster jobs with this configuration like this (thanks @JulianCienfuegos):

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster project-spark.py
```

This way you can't see the output in the terminal, and the command exits as soon as the job is submitted (not completed).

You can also use `--deploy-mode client` to see the output right there in your terminal but just do this for testing, since the job gets canceled if the command is interrupted (e.g. you press `Ctrl+C`, or your session ends)

Comment: Why on only one machine? I have two name nodes and 4 data nodes. I'm getting some weird behavior and I wonder if that is because there are many different spark installs? They are all identical, however.

Also how do you know that he wants a shell and not to submit a cluster job? For my purpose I want to submit cluster jobs.Does your solution handle that case as well?

Comment: @JulianCienfuegos, Why only on one machine? I'm not entirely sure why and how, but I guess spark sends all the required libraries (spark libraries and codes) along with your code to every worker, so the workers don't need to have spark pre-installed. It was strange to me at first too, but I did test this and it works.
I updated my answer to include submitting jobs.